# Magento C# RestApi bug

Tags: c#, rest, magento, oauth

I am a newbie with c#, but since I have trouble using Delphi to connect to Magento through REST with oAuth.... I decided to start tring to do it with C#

I searched the web for a solution, and found the **Magento.RestApi** library, that seems to be very up to date.
Being a newbie and all, it took me a little time until I succeeded to set up my environment for testing, so here is what I did:
- after installing Visual Studio 2015 Comunity, I started a new project, then from inside it, I accessed the Package Manager Console and ran this command:

```
Install-Package Magento.RestApi
```

After this, I placed a button on the form, and onClick, I added this code:

```
var client = new MagentoApi()
.SetCustomAdminUrlPart("index.php/admin")
.Initialize("http://www.example.com/magento/", "77896eyrf34i37873gh7389h7e3fg34", "u837h743488dg38g8384433423")
.AuthenticateAdmin("adminuser", "adminpassword");
```

Of course I added the using clause in the code:

```
using Magento.RestApi;
```

Also the parameters of Initialize are the ones required... with key and secret.
As far as I understand (from no documentation at all) this is supposed to instantiate a Magento RestAPI object that would allow me to interfece with my magento store.

When I run the code and click the button this is what I get:

```
Exception thrown: 'Magento.RestApi.MagentoApiException' in Magento.RestApi.dll

Additional information: The provided admin username 'adminuser' or password is invalid. The user needs to be a Magento admin.
```

The thing is: the user is perfect, it's my admin user, the password is correct. The REST Role of the user is set up in the backend of my Magento store, and all the rest of the setup is done in the backend so that REST would be enabled.

On another note, I tried to investigate what this library does and I installed ***Fiddler***... only to discover that in fact the error page returned by my store is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /magento/oauth/initiate was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

(this was the TextView from Fiddler)

So apparently, the URL of my REST call is wrong? Or my store is not set up correctly?

Also the oAuth seems to be used because in the request (also Fiddler) the Auth tab I have this:

```
No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.

Authorization Header is present: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888",oauth_consumer_key="77896eyrf34i37873gh7389h7e3fg34",oauth_nonce="kldcjldvnldgkll",oauth_signature="jkiu3i5i5hbikh%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1448717978",oauth_version="1.0"
```

Comment: Is your shop really under `/magento/`? [Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html) it gives an example URI of `/oauth/initiate`.

Comment: I know the article, but it does not help me much. My actual URL of my shop (frontend) is `http://www.example.com/magento/` while my admin URL (backend) is `http://www.example.com/magento/index.php/admin`. Is there any way (some dummy REST Client app with oAuth) that I can populate with my keys and secrets, and destination test URL so I can see that I am using the right URL to connect? So, some client that is flawless, So I'll know that the problem lies with my shop's configuration and not the client?

Comment: The 404 error says: `<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.example.com Port 80</address>` - you're not connecting to `www.example.com` are you?

Comment: `www.example.com` is the recommended URL by SO so that I would not expose my server's address. Naturally the URL I try to access is the real one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It was a server side issue.
I had to add some settings to the ***httpd.conf*** file. I mean I had to check what version of Apache I have installed (2.2.3) 
Depending on your Linux falvour, the apache config file might be named differently and may be located somewhere else, but for my CENTOS, the location was:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

then in httpd.conf I added:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/www.example.com/magento/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Also because I use VirtualHosts, I needed to add this settings inside the Virtual Host TAG that is hosting my magento

After adding the settings, I restarted the appache service like:

```
service httpd restart
```

and now I can finally connect to my REST webservice using the C# library.

> (I still have issues) if I try to test connecting to the REST service
>   with oAuth from Firefox's RESTClient. Over there I get a strange error
>   message:

```
oauth_problem=nonce_used
```

but as long as I can connect with C#, I am going to ignore this issue.